# The proper protocol in compareing differences between correlation matrices?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, normalization, matrix

Given 3 groups of individuals (regardless them being humans, cats, dogs), if I need to compare differences in correlation matrices (eigenvalue variances) between those groups (let say they are 3 different breeds of dogs), and let say I wanna exclude the effect of sex, weight and height, should I first pool all 3 groups together, fit a linear model for those factors,take residual values after regression and then split residuals according to groups in order to compare the differences in correlation matrices, or should I first split the groups do a linear model for each, calculate residuals and then compare the differences in correlation matrices between groups?

Comment: Why do you want to compare correlation matrices? What is your goal?

Comment: the goal is to explore differences in integration level (based on different traits)  between different groups.

Comment: OK, so .... why look at correlation matrices? Look at a regression with integration level as the DV